# Combine two JSON strings

Tags: ruby

I have two json:

```
json_a = {"ak1":"av1","ak2":"av2"}
```

and

```
json_b = {"bk1":"bv1","bk2":"bv2"}
```

how to create:

```
json_result = {"ak1":"av1","ak2":"av2", "bk1":"bv1","bk2":"bv2"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Easiest and least error-prone:

```
require 'json'
JSON.dump(JSON.parse(json_a).merge(JSON.parse(json_b)))
```

(assuming your code is wrong and actually does have strings and not syntax-error hashes).